# Infragistics UltraGrid summary value from cell

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have this ultraGrid:

http://s4.postimg.org/fhnjs4w4d/Capture.png

I need to pass to summary cell a custom value from column with red mark on picture.

Infragistics lets me put  the Max, Min, Sum, Average, etc in summary cell, but I need to pass custom value.

Any help?

I have this code wich put Max value:

```
     Dim columnToSummarizeVlrAq As UltraGridColumn = ugbBens.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns(ugbBensColVlrAq)

 Dim summaryVlrAq As SummarySettings = .Add(ugbBensColVlrAq,SummaryType.Maximum, columnToSummarizeVlrAq, SummaryPosition.UseSummaryPositionColumn)
```

Here the solution :

Create a new class:

```
Public Class MyCustomSummarySettings
    Implements ICustomSummaryCalculator

    Private valor As Object = 0

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Val()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BeginCustomSummary(ByVal summarySettings As SummarySettings, ByVal rows As RowsCollection) Implements ICustomSummaryCalculator.BeginCustomSummary
        valor = 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub AggregateCustomSummary(ByVal summarySettings As SummarySettings, ByVal row As UltraGridRow) Implements ICustomSummaryCalculator.AggregateCustomSummary

        'Primeiro mês
        If summarySettings.Key = "COL_DeprAntExVlrRv" Then
            If row.Index = 0 Then valor = CDbl(row.Cells("COL_DeprAntExVlrRv").Value)
        End If

        If summarySettings.Key = "fltVlrDepreciavelAct" Then
            If row.Index = 0 Then valor = CDbl(row.Cells("fltVlrDepreciavelAct").Value)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Function EndCustomSummary(ByVal summarySettings As SummarySettings, ByVal rows As RowsCollection) As Object Implements ICustomSummaryCalculator.EndCustomSummary
        Return valor
    End Function
End Class
```

And call class with summary type custom, like this:

```
Dim custumSummary As New MyCustomSummarySettings

summaryDepreciavel = .Add(ugbBensColDepreciavelAceite, SummaryType.Custom, custumSummary, columnToSummarizeDepreciavel, SummaryPosition.UseSummaryPositionColumn, Nothing) '7ª Coluna
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim custumSummary As New MyCustomSummarySettings

summaryDepreciavel = .Add(ugbBensColDepreciavelAceite, SummaryType.Custom, custumSummary, columnToSummarizeDepreciavel, SummaryPosition.UseSummaryPositionColumn, Nothing)
```